# Xaml, add button over image in a stackpanel programmatically

Tags: windows, xaml

For my windows8App, i need to have an image with a play button over it.
I created a grid, The grid contains a stackplan. And i want to place the image and the button over the image programmatically. But when i run the app, i see that the button goes behind the image.
My question first question is if it is a good way to put button over an image?
If yes then what is wrong with my code?

```
<Border x:Name="videoPlayerBr" BorderBrush="#FFDED5D5"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="400" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Row="0">
 <StackPanel Name="videoPlayerSP">
 </StackPanel>
 </Border>
```

this is the code behind:

```
        var proVideoImg = new Image();
        proVideoImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        proVideoImg.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
        videoPlayerSP.Children.Add(proVideoImg);

        var playBtn = new Button();
        playBtn.Margin = new Thickness(136, 121, 0, 133);
        ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
        brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/playbutton.png"));
        playBtn.Background = brush1;        
        playBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(PlayVideo_Button_Click);
        videoPlayerSP.Children.Add(playBtn);
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place you Image and Button controls in a Canvas or a nested Grid instead.

Comment: Thanks, I have put them in a Canvas. But Now when I put the mouse over the button, the button disappears. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly rolled out a solution. Here you go.  I hope you can convert it to C# easily?

```
      <Button Height="29" Width="82" Click="Button_Click">
        <Button.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Icons/add_action.png" Stretch="Fill" Opacity=".2"/>
                    <Path Data="M13,9.8933333 L13,21.561587 23.2164,16.328076 z" Fill="#FFBED460" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Width="11.212" RenderTransformOrigin="0.357,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="15">
                        <Path.Stroke>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF9B6262" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Path.Stroke>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>             
            </Button.Content>                   
        </Button>
```